# Ubuntu with Thunderbolt Dock - Won't initialize thunderbolt unless HDMI plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, thunderbolt

Ubuntu 22.04 - Dell WD22TB4 dock. Intel Xe graphics on 12h Gen i5 NUC.

Ubuntu only seems to initialize the thunderbolt display output if an HDMI output is connected at some point.

1. Boot with just Thunderbolt connected -> No output
2. Boot with just
   Thunderbolt connected, connect HDMI once booted -> Output, can then
   disconnect HDMI

Hotplugging the TB4 dock instead of connecting an HDMI cable doesn't enable display output.

It feels like Ubuntu isn't activating display output unless it sees a directly connected monitor (as opposed to via TB Dock)